# excel 356 serialisation numbering

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I can't conceive of the function expression I could use that would result in the following number set. To be clear, column A is my source data, column B is the result I want - but by using a formula expression.

> ## ColA   ColB
>
> ```
> cat    1  
> cat    2  
> cat    3  
> dog    1  
> dog    2  
> mouse  1  
> mouse  2  
> mouse  3  
> mouse  4  
> rat    1  
> rat    2
> ```

Quite simply all I want to do is to serialise a number from 1 to n to every entry in ColA. All ColA entries will be grouped together but not necessarily in alphabetical order.  The function would go in ColB and it's result would be the serial numbers shown above.

I can't use the outline/grouping tool because there must not be splits/gaps in the other columns (there's around 1,000 columns in the real dataset) - and the entries will have additional entries of the same element inserted into the middle of their group (by hand) - so the ideal function will also relative to it's row predecessor.

I can't (don't want) to do the task manually because in the real data set the column is over 6,000 entries and many many variations (but all ordered).

Can anyone help?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698632/how-do-i-enumerate-duplicate-rows-in-excel

basically if your data is ColA 
put this in B1: `=COUNTIF(A1,A1)` 
and this in B2 and on `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)`

I have an older version of Excel, but that should still work.

Additionally, the data do not have to be together to be counted, if that's a problem.

Comment: Thank you Seeds. I hoped it would be that simple. Perfect.